Bad output with Cyrillic text in the context of German
in Overleaf i got no errornumber, but in the output i got for „Маша живёт“ instead „ “ ist 3. Person ...
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, german]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{russian}
\section*{Часть 1: Рассказ на русском языке}

Маша живёт в Москве.

\newpage
\selectlanguage{german}
\section*{Teil 2: Übersetzung auf Deutsch mit grammatikalischen Erläuterungen}

\textbf{Masha lebt in Moskau.} \\
„Маша живёт“ ist 3. Person Singular Präsens von \textit{жить} (leben). Die Endung \textit{-ёт} ist typisch für Verben der 1. Konjugation im Präsens.

\end{document}


ChatGTP's responses for LaTeX can only be described with a 4-letter word.

Off-topic: The geometry options left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm may be expressed more parsimoniously as margin=20mm.

Contrary to what you say, LaTeX raises error messages, the first of which being
! LaTeX Error: Command \CYRM unavailable in encoding OT1.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.18 „М

In the context of German, you need to tell TeX that you want words in Russian: it doesn't understand language as you do.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian, ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{russian}
\section*{Часть 1: Рассказ на русском языке}

Маша живёт в Москве.

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\section*{Teil 2: Übersetzung auf Deutsch mit grammatikalischen Erläuterungen}

\textbf{Masha lebt in Moskau.}

„\foreignlanguage{russian}{Маша живёт}“ ist 3.~Person Singular Präsens
von \textit{\foreignlanguage{russian}{жить}} (leben). Die Endung
\textit{\foreignlanguage{russian}{-ёт}} ist typisch für Verben der
1.~Konjugation im Präsens.

\end{document}


Note ngerman for “neu Rechtschreibung” compliance and also 3.~Person and 1.~Konjugation that avoids bad line breaks and extended space. Also T1 is recommended.
Addendum
The suggestion by ChatGPT to remove \selectlanguage{ngerman} is utterly wrong.
